# Show specific user details in Django application instead of all details

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

I am creating my first Django project . I have taken 30,000 values as input and want to show particular values according to primary key .

Code:

```
class employeesList(APIView):

def get(self,request):
    employees1 = employees.objects.all()

    with open('tracking_ids.csv') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            _, created = employees.objects.get_or_create(
            AWB=row[0],
            Pickup_Pincode=row[1],
            Drop_Pincode=row[2],
            )
    serializer = employeesSerializer(employees1 , many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)

def post(self,request):
    # employees1 = employees.objects.get(id=request.employees.AWB)
    employees1 = employees.objects.all()
    serializer = employeesSerializer(employees1 , many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

If I enter http://127.0.0.1:8000/employees/ in URL , I get all the values . I want the URL to be like http://127.0.0.1:8000/employees/P01001168074 and show values of P01001168074 where P01001168074 is primary ID .

I have read 
1:[showing the model values of specific user django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14826699/showing-the-model-values-of-specific-user-django)
2)[editing user details in python django rest framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44730943/editing-user-details-in-python-django-rest-framework)
but they are different

Can it be done and if it can , then how ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presuming that you are using Django 2.0 you must configure a path than can capture your parameter [as seen in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/#captured-parameters)

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer

class A(models.Model):
    x = models.CharField(max_length=250)


class MySerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = A
        fields = ('x',)


class MyListView(APIView):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # simply get all the objects, serialize and return the response
        elems = A.objects.all()
        response_data = MySerializer(elems, many=True).data
        return Response(data=response_data)


class MyDetailView(APIView):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # we obtain the parameter from the URL
        desired_item = kwargs.get("desired_item", None)

        # we filter the objects by it and get our instance
        element = A.objects.filter(x=desired_item).first()

        # serialize the instance and return the response
        response_data = MySerializer(element).data
        return Response(data=response_data)

# all we have to now is define the paths for the list and the detail views.
urlpatterns = [
    path('employees/', MyListView.as_view()),
    path('employees/<str:desired_item>', MyDetailView.as_view())
]
```

Comment: Getting below error :Exception Type: TypeError at /employees/P01001198206
Exception Value: post() got an unexpected keyword argument 'desired_item'

Comment: @kishankeswani well depends how you implemented it. It's rather vague for me what you just mentioned.

Comment: I will look into this error . BTW one question , to populate these 30,000 values , I used get in views.py but it took 1 hour for sqlite3 , any faster approach to populate these values ?

Comment: @kishankeswani 30.000 is a lot. Paginate the result.

Comment: Thanks and I found my error ; I had not changed x to primary key column

Answer (score 1):

One good option is to use a `viewset` that already includes a list and detail endpoint and requires little to code for a default simple setup

## views.py

```
from rest_framework import viewsets


class EmployeeViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = EmployeeSerializer
    queryset = Employee.objects.all()
```

## urls.py

```
from rest_framework.routers import SimpleRouter
from views import EmployeeViewSet


router = SimpleRouter()
router.register(r'employees', EmployeeViewSet, base_name='employees')

urlpatterns = router.get_urls()
```

You can read more about viewsets in the [DRF docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/)